# Download (Get the Stream) of file using wcf of sharepoint 2010 async

Tags: c#, wcf, sharepoint-2010

hello i want get file from wcf  of sharepoint 2010.

the only methode the context  give :

context.BeginGetReadStream

context.EndGetReadStream

i did a lot of of researchers there no any answers

Comment: The question doesn't show what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

```
        var response = context.BeginGetReadStream(MyFile, _args, (ar) =>
        {
            using (System.IO.FileStream output = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                aDS.EndGetReadStream(ar).Stream.CopyTo(output);
            }


        }, null);
```

this is the solution and it's working